# How to rename a file name with different extension in python

Tags: python-2.7

I have a code to rename file names which having extension ".dtshd".

```
import fnmatch
import os
import csv
import glob

with open('New_Names.csv') as f:
          file_pattern = '*.dtshd*'
          file_names = {}
          reader = csv.reader(f)
          for row in reader:
              file_names[row[0]] = row[1]
for file in glob.glob(file_pattern):
        path, filename = os.path.split(file)
        filename_noext, ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
        new_filename = file_names.get(filename_noext, filename_noext)
        os.rename(os.path.join(path, filename),
             os.path.join(path, '{}{}'.format(new_filename, '.bin')))
```

This is working fine.But i need to rename a file name with ".cpt" extension also.How do i add this in my code.Can you please guide me this.

Comment: It seems that you copy-pasted this code from somewhere and don't really understand it. Take a few minutes/hours to understand it, and you will find that what you are asking is extremely trivial.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at `pathlib` (it is not included the standard library in Python 2, though) and `shutil`.

```
from pathlib import Path
import shutil

for file in Path(".").glob(file_pattern):
    shutil.move(str(file), str(file.with_suffix(".cpt")))
```